# What can we [infer] from this?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

There are currently two similarly named tags, and some of the questions are related to the [Facebook Infer tool](https://fbinfer.com/):
- [infer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infer) - 21 questions (no wiki)
- [facebook-infer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-infer) - newly created tag, two questions (no wiki)

What should [infer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infer) be devoted to? If it is about type inference, then we should retag other questions to [facebook-infer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-infer).

Comment: If facebook-infer is unambiguous, move all the questions towards that one. Then check what's left of the infer tag.

Comment: @Braiam yes, it is unambiguous. I'm more concerned about future questions that will be created and use wrong tag by mistake.

Comment: The first step is to use the "correct" tag. Facebook infer, despite not having tag excerpt is pretty clear what the question is about. If you find a better tag for a question, isn't your prerogative to use the better tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a bunch of questions about the word "infer" and not the FB "infer", which I retagged. Amongst those some (10) were related to Type inference, I tagged them with [type-inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-inference).

There were a couple of questions related to a R library called infer, which I tagged with [r-infer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-infer).

Looks like there were just 6 questions left with the [infer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infer) tag, after the cleanup. I merged the remaining questions in the tag with [facebook-infer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-infer).

Given that 10 of the questions were related to [type-inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-inference) as opposed to 6 related to FB's infer tool, I made [infer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infer) a synonym of [type-inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-inference).

The next step is to add a tag wiki to the [facebook-infer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-infer), after which we can place bets on whether that'll be sponsored some day.

Comment: Somebody already created a wiki, and I've proposed an excerpt

Comment: 10 reputation on Facebook claiming it.